# Реакция на касание дочерних объектов кнопки (Unity)

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Всем привет, добавил в Unity кнопку, к ней прикрепил изображение, "хитбокс" изображения выходит за "хитбокс" кнопки. При нажатии на "хитбокс" изображения кнопка реагирует на нажатие. Как это поправить? То есть, я хочу чтобы дочерний объект не реагировал на касание

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Raycast target.